# Image drop to previous position

Tags: android, image, touch

Touch listener not work. I need to drag the image over screen and drop to previous position itself.

For that i write the code as below:

```
class Mylistener implements OnTouchListener{

        @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams()); 
              layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();


                //int left=0,top=0;
                switch(event.getActionMasked())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         startx=(int) event.getRawX();
                         starty=(int) event.getRawY();
                         System.out.println("ACTION DOWN: "+startx+","+starty);
                        break; 
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


                       int  left = (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2);
                      int top = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                     marginParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                     v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                         marginParams.setMargins(startx, starty, 0, 0);
                         layoutParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                         System.out.println("ACTION UP: "+startx+","+starty);

                         v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2); 
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

    }
```

But it drag over the screen and not drop in the previous position. Please provide me any help

Comment: Save coordinates of image before dragging(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN). As soon as you left(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP), set saved position to image...

Answer (score 2):

In Ur ACTION_DOWN Event, record the cooordinates of the touched imageView as

```
// Global Declarations
float v_origX,v_origY; // Used for original X and Y of ImageViews

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
{
.....
v_origX=v.getX();
v_origY=v.getY();
}
```

and then in ACTION_UP event,

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
{
if(condition_fulfilled)
{
 // do ur stuff
}
else
{
// set the imageView back to original position
v.setX(v_origX);
    v.setY(v_origY);
}

}
```